# Executing multiple SQL Server stored procedures in C# with the same parameters

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

Curious to know if I execute multiple stored procedures within the same using block, will the parameters be passed to each stored procedure or will I need to explicitly add the same parameters to each individual stored procedure.

```
using (sqlConnection)
{
    SQLCommand cmd = new SQLCommand("sproc1", sqlConnection)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //adding parameters for the first SQL query
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLParameter("@ID", id));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLParameter("@Sport", sportId));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLParameter("@Player", playerId));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = "sproc2";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    //Will parameters from above be passed in this stored procedure, or will they need to be added again?
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
};
```

Comment: What's stopping you from trying it on your own?

Comment: that will work, but don't. maintenance nightmare / bad practice.

Comment: Parameters and other `SqlCommand` state *are* preserved between `Execute...` calls.

Comment: @dlatikay Reusing `SqlCommand` instances is not a bad-practice in itself.

Comment: @Dai I'd agree if there was some logical grouping of those procedures, like a consistent naming scheme and a clear rule that they all share the same set of parameters.

Comment: note that your using block is around the connection, not the command. `SqlCommand` is also `IDisposable` and should have its own using block.

Comment: @TJWolschon apologize for leaving the detail out about being curious of best practices as well.

Comment: Thank you everyone else for giving insight on it is possible and opinion on practice but I believe @levininja has answered my question thoroughly.

Comment: Also note that SqlCommand is disposable so should be in a `using` block.

Comment: @Richardissimo and dlatikay duely noted, thank you for pointing that out as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  However I would not do that for three maintenance reasons:

1. It's not normal (at least I have never seen this), so this code may be misread by other developers or future you.
2. If only some of the parameters are reused but not all, you end up having new `Add()`s for each stored procedure. And then it's difficult to keep track, as you read the code, which exact parameters are used for any given stored procedure.
3. The different stored procedure calls are no longer modular. Each one relies on what has previously been added to the parameters in the `SQLCommand`.

If you do find yourself reusing a group of variables between different stored procedure calls, then I would just create a method that adds those variables to a `SQLCommand` and returns the `SQLCommand`, and then call that method for each of the stored procedures.

Yes that is a tiny amount of extra processing time, but it will make your code much more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for the response on this @levininja because I was only thinking in terms of just me using it and not best practice for those following up behind me.

Comment: to answer your question about same parameters across the multiple sprocs, yes each of the sprocs contain the same parameters so I may look into creating a method that takes care of that for me.